# boundingRectWithSize similar function in android

Tags: android, text, textview

`boundingRectWithSize` is an API on iOS which will calculate the size of a string constrained to a given width and height. Is there a similar function on Android?

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size 
                       options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options 
                    attributes:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)attributes 
                       context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context;
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrectwithsize